# How to make button clickable while animating tanslateX() property with :active class?

Tags: html, css

I have a button that I want to animate and make it move right when is clicked. When clicking again it should return to previews position.

The problem is that the click is not registering and as `translateX` value is increased (ex: -80px) more un-clickable the button becomes and for `translateX(-10px)` button is clickable but I want to translate more.

How do I make the button clickable and also translate it with higher value, ex `translateX(-60px)`. (Clickable in here means the event is captured in javascript using 'on-click' event)

```css
.button{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left:10px;
    background-color: white;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black;
    padding:4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    background-image:url('../public/icons/left.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    transition: transform .6s;
    &:hover{
        background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    }
    &:active {
        box-shadow:none;
        // when button is clicked it should feel like button moved left,like in slider left button 
        // goes to right and comes back when clicked
        transform: translateX(-40px);
    }
}
```

```html
<i class="button">Next</i>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for rewriting the code. You want something like this?

```js
$("div").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("move");        
});
```

```css
div{
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    width:33px;
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: red;
    transition: transform .6s;
}
.move{
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>click me</div>
```

Comment: is there any way to achieve this with the only CSS?

Comment: @Noogrammer you could try it with a checkbox

Comment: @Noogrammer can I ask why? .. Yes you can but I consider it to be more of a mess... check this link https://codepen.io/dcode-software/pen/qBbGrLz and here you can find a video that explains it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQVkA6cOBiI&list=PLfmi5pQYsS8Pj62BbITGfdtItWePl9BzQ&index=12